# What does it mean when someone uses two periods?

Tags: punctuation, semantics, non-native-english

In past communications with non-native English speakers, I occasionally see the use of two periods.

Some examples:

> Ok.. let's meet soon.
>
> Sounds good..
>
> Thursday Meeting..

This seems to show up mostly in informal communication. It looks to be some kind of half-ellipsis.

Where does this come from and what is the intended meaning?

Comment: In the English language it should be 3 dots representing an Ellipsis.  It indicates an omission or suppression of letters or words.

Comment: In my opinion it's almost certainly a typo. Without context I can't tell you whether they meant to put one period or two.